# What are the benefits of Weblogic over Jboss / Glassfish in production?

Tags: jboss, weblogic, java

I'd like to ask those of you running weblogic server in production, what benefits do you see in using it compared to Jboss and Glassfish?

Comment: If you call a large hole in your budget a benefit, then you'll achieve that quite easily.  Sorry, can't stand Oracle's licensing structure...

Comment: Ok, that's one way to look at it, but enterprises use Weblogic. There must be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that there is no tangible benefit of Weblogic over any other Java app server. They truly all perform well enough to solve most every problem that JEE solves. So why do some people pay 10X more for the Oracle/ BEA brand ?!

Good salesman at Oracle- that is the answer. It's really that simple. If you ask the sales force they will claim better support, ease of installation ,or ease of management - but all of these issues are good for JBoss and Glassfish too.

For example, Oracle sales may offer "free Weblogic with $1MM in Oracle!". These kinds of sales really work. Red Hat has a much smaller sales force, and Oracle has a 20-year head start. So the battle continues.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit I'm biased towards Weblogic (working with it since 2001)  BUT I'm not the one footing the bill, so I'll keep the substantial license costs out of the equation. Weblogic licenses are per-processor (when I last checked).

In the earlier days of heavy EJBs (circa 2004) Weblogic was the most stable app server and easiest to configure and monitor for a production instance. The console was and still is quite useful in tracking and isolating a variety of things that can go wrong around DB connections, EJBs not deployed, missing JNDI lookups etc.

Today with the advent of Spring and light-weight containers, JBoss and Glassfish are both considered suitable production servers. Hey, anything but Websphere ;)
So there isnt much of a push towards Weblogic, probably the smart sales pitch does it.

Also see [this comparison](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/o-application-servers-where-art-thou/)